# Get elevation data w.r.t. date in Google Earth

Tags: google-earth

I am using Google Earth Pro to get the elevation of different points on earth. It's giving me elevation data for points I am hovering over, but I want to get the elevation data with respect to date.

For example, When I put a `placemark` and hover on it, its elevation is 1465 ft. but when I move the date few years ago, the Earth view changes, but the elevation value is still the same.

Is it possible to see elevation data with respect to date changes? It's surely going to be changed with time, and sea level. Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the short [tour].